# Passing a value from Activity to Fragment in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin

I created a bottom navigation activity in my project, which contains one activity and two fragments. In Main Activity I have value stored in a variable but if I pass the value to the fragments then I am getting NullPointer Exception error. I am using kotlin in my project and any help is appreciated.
**Expectation**

```
Get Value into Fragment from MainActivity. MainActivity--->TestOneFragment
```

**Language Used**

```
Kotlin
```

**Main Activity**

```
class Test : AppCompatActivity(), BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
    private val KEY_POSITION = "keyPosition"
    private var navPosition: BottomNavigationPosition = BottomNavigationPosition.ONE
    private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    private lateinit var bottomNavigation: BottomNavigationView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        restoreSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        bottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        initBottomNavigation()
        initFragment(savedInstanceState)
        var Name:String=intent.getStringExtra("name")
        println("Test CLLicked: $Name")


        //This code is to pass the value to Fragment
        var bundle=Bundle()
        bundle.putString("name",Name)
        var frag=TestFragment()
        frag.arguments=bundle
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?)
    {
        outState?.putInt(KEY_POSITION, navPosition.id)
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean
    {
        navPosition = findNavigationPositionById(item.itemId)
        return switchFragment(navPosition)
    }

    private fun restoreSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        savedInstanceState?.also {
            val id = it.getInt(KEY_POSITION, BottomNavigationPosition.ONE.id)
            navPosition = findNavigationPositionById(id)
        }
    }

    private fun initBottomNavigation()
    {
        bottomNavigation.active(navPosition.position)
        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }

    private fun initFragment(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        savedInstanceState ?: switchFragment(BottomNavigationPosition.ONE)
    private fun switchFragment(navPosition: BottomNavigationPosition): Boolean {
        return supportFragmentManager.findFragment(navPosition).let {
            if (it.isAdded) return false
            supportFragmentManager.detach() // Extension function
            supportFragmentManager.attach(it, navPosition.getTag()) // Extension function
            supportFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()
        }
    }
    private fun FragmentManager.findFragment(position: BottomNavigationPosition): Fragment
    {
        return findFragmentByTag(position.getTag()) ?: position.createFragment()
    }
}
```

**TestOneFragment**

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val testName= arguments!!.getString("name")
....
}
```

**Error**

```
kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
```

Comment: You can share proper logs like where you are getting NPE and try to add more details of your code like in which function you are passing/accessing the data etc.

Comment: when are you calling arguments!!.getString("name")?

As well, try to avoid force unwrapping (using !!) in your code.

Comment: @AdrianComan thanks for your comment. If I do then I am getting null in my variable output.  val testName= arguments?.getString("name")

Comment: correct, because arguments is null, but when or where in the code are you calling it? can you post a sample of your fragment class?

Comment: I am calling this inside onCreateView function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is an example of the `newInstance` pattern for creating `Fragments`.

This is within a `companion object`, which is pretty much just a way to say "these things are Static."

First, you should define constants for your `Bundle` names, this will help keep everything aligned. Next, define a `newInstance` method that takes your parameters, such as the `name`.

And within there, you will create your `Fragment` and return it. This way, your `Activity` doesn't have to worry about the `Bundle` or anything. All your logic is within one place, for storing/retrieving, all within your `Fragment`.

```
class TestOneFragment {

    companion object {
        const val ARG_NAME = "name"


        fun newInstance(name: String): TestOneFragment {
            val fragment = TestOneFragment()

            val bundle = Bundle().apply {
                putString(ARG_NAME, name)
            }

            fragment.arguments = bundle

            return fragment
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val name = arguments?.getString(ARG_NAME)
        // ...
    }
}
```

And now, you can easily get your `Fragment` by doing the following.

```
class Test : AppCompatActivity(), BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // ...

        val name = intent.getStringExtra("name")

        // Creating the new Fragment with the name passed in.
        val fragment = TestFragment.newInstance(name)
    }

}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you explain little bit more about MyActivity code. I am not sure where to write that piece of code like either in activity or in fragment

Comment: @JoshJo - The `MyActivity` code goes into whatever `Activity` you're in. Say you're on your `MainActivity` and you want to show your `TestOneFragment`, your `MainActivity` can call the `TestOneFragment.newInstance("name")`, get the `Fragment` all prepared, and just display it however you want to.

Comment: If you edit your question to include how you're going to display your `Fragment` in your `MainActivty`, I'll edit my answer to be more specific.

Comment: I am looking otherway round. I need to get Activity Value into Fragment. MainActivity---->TestOneFragment

Comment: Yes, I understand. `MainActivty` has some data, and you want to create a new `Fragment` with that data. Right?

Comment: @JoshJo Okay, edit your question to include more of your `MainActivity` code, to include what you want to do with the new `Fragment`, and I'll edit my answer to help more.

Comment: @JoshJo, Ok, I updated my code to kind of use your code for an example of how you'd use that in your actual code. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: still getting null value after the above changes.

Comment: @JoshJo I think it may be related to how you're using the `Fragment`. In the `MainActivity` class, you're not actually using that instance. You're just creating it, and ignoring it. How are you using your `Fragments`? Are you creating them some other way?

Comment: Add the entire callstack, it should point to the exact line that has a `KotlinNullPointerException`.

Comment: What if I am using NavigationHost which then automatically creates the Fragments?